# Tensor product of commutative rings

Tags: ring-theory

I need help with this question: 
Suppose that A, B, C are commutative rings with unit. Is it true that $A\otimes_\mathbb{Z}(B\times C)$ is **isomorphic as rings** with $(A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} B)\times(A\otimes_\mathbb{Z} C)$?

If you have a reference or a counterexample that would be great.

Note: Here $\otimes$ = tensor product or rings and $\times$=direct product of rings.

P.S. On the web I found a positive answer, but I don't see how the universal properties of tensor product and direct product can be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is true. It does not follow from the universal properties alone but is special to the category of commutative rings: it says that the opposite category, namely the category of affine schemes, is distributive (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category).

Answer (score 4):

First, I think that writing an explicit isomorphism is pretty straightforward and you don't need to appeal to universal mapping properties.

There is an obvious set map
$$
 \phi\colon A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}(B\times C)\to (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}B)\times (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}C), \quad \sum a_i\otimes(b_i,c_i)\mapsto (\sum a_i\otimes b_i, \sum a_i\otimes c_i).
$$
Then show that it is injective, surjective and a ring morphism.

However, you could show this by using the universal mapping property of the coproduct (=tensor product) or the product (=direct product). If you want to show $(A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}B)\times (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}C)$ is isomorphic to $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}(B\times C)$ it is enough to show it has the universal mapping property of the coproduct of $A$ and $B\times C$, i.e., you show that there are ring morphisms $s_1\colon A\to (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} B)\times(A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} C)$ and $s_2\colon B\times C\to (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} B)\times(A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} C)$ such that every other pair $f\colon A\to T$ and $g\colon B\times C\to T$ induces a unique factorization $h\colon (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} B)\times(A\otimes_{\mathbb Z} C)\to T$.

You could also do this the other way around by showing $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}(B\times C)$ satisfies the universal mapping property of the product of $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}B$ and $A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}C$.

I don't think this is easier than explicitly giving an isomorphism by elements. But you can also try to find such maps as an exercise in this line of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

It is true for modules and for $\mathbf Z$-algebras: tensor product commutes with direct sums and finite products.